# HTTP server using WCF for simple project - is it worth it?

Tags: .net, wcf, httplistener, httpserver

I need to have HTTP server embedded in my .NET application. Simply, there will be two dynamically generated views, but one can said - there will be just two different pages. Is it worth to use WCF as presented in blog post: [Building a Basic Web Server Using WCF](http://blog.iserviceoriented.com/index.php/2010/01/23/building-a-basic-web-server-using-wcf/) for such a simple task? Would it be just easier and better in this case to use `HttpListener` class?

Comment: What kind of clients are going to be consuming the service? Web browsers? Windows Services? Do you need to serve the response in a variety of different formats? Json, XML, binary?

Comment: As for now we are planning to serve those really simple pages to web browsers, and as always - I don't have much time for spending to many time on that ;) But I think I know what you are trying to say :) WCF way if there will be a chance to serve for different kind of clients?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WCF's strength is to serve data to a lot of different clients in a lot of different formats. If this is just going to be a simple web page and the browser is the only client, I would say that WCF is not worth it. ASMX is much simpler and easy to use. WCF is *supposed* to be the way of the future but that doesnt mean ASMX is totally useless yet.

I have never used the HttpListener class so unfortunately I can't comment on if it is a good idea or not.